# How do you iteratively count nodes in a BST (C++)?

Tags: c++, count, iteration, binary-search-tree, nodes

I already know how to implement this function recursively. This is what I have:

```
int nodeCount(node *root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1 + nodeCount(root->left) + nodeCount(root->right);
}
```

I would now like to perform a node count without recursion.

Comment: why dont you want to use recursion?

Comment: Without recursion you'd need to store the nodes you need to look at in a data structure such as a stack or queue. At that point you're basically doing "manual" recursion.

Comment: I'm trying to fully understand the pros, cons, and implementations of recursion v. iteration. I've tried looking for an iterative version of this code relentlessly, without success. I just don't know what it looks like or how it would work.

Comment: @CaptainAmericode did you change your name inbetween, or what is going on here?

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, I did. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack` or `queue` for instance.

Btw. You may want to look at [Tail recursion wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

```
int nodeCount(node * root)
{
  int counter = 0;
  stack<node*> v; // a container with remaining nodes "to check"
  v.push(root); // first node "to check"
  while (v.size() > 0) // while there is something "to check"
    {
      node * n = v.top(); // take element from the top of stack
      v.pop(); // remove that element from the top of stack
      if (n != NULL) // if node is valid
        {
          counter++; // count it
          v.push(n->left); // and add
          v.push(n->right); // his children to the stack
        }
    }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: @JamesRoot Then, how would you fix the issue with `n == nullptr`? Add something like `if (root == NULL) return 0;` before the loop?